# Structure packing in C

Tags: c++, c, structure, qt-creator

I have a structure:

```
**struct PROCESSING
{
    PROCESSOR Byte ;
    uint16_t count ;
    uint8_t overrange ;
    Status status ;
    Time timestamp ;
    float Field;
    float temperature ;
    float adc1;
    float dac1;
    float Field2;
    float Temperature;
    float adc2 ;
    float dac2 ;
};
PTC_STATIC_ASSERT_SIZE(Processing, 45U);**
```

This structure actual structure is 45U , but when I build I get an error:
"Invalid Application of sizeof to incomplete type "

I need to pack it to exactly 45U.

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I've worked with a couple of C++ frameworks, and errors like those are always baffling to me. You need to tag this as C or C++ to get one of those gcc gurus in here.

Comment: Is "Processing" declared somewhere else? Because the struct you're defining is PROCESSING. (So if there's a "struct Processing;" line somewhere and the code is really as it reads, you get that error)

Comment: "Invalid Application of sizeof to incomplete type" means that the compiler has been told that a type exists (via a forward declaration) but the compiler hasn't been told what the type actually is... which is why the sizeof() operator (which is presumably being invoked by the PTC_STATIC_ASSERT_SIZE macro, somehow) is failing to compile.  You might need to #include a header that contains the actual declaration of PROCESSOR or Status or time or etc before the above code (instead of or in addition to the header that just does a forward declaration).

Comment: No , the structure is not defined anywhere else in the program

Comment: What's PROCESSOR, Status and Time?

Comment: **Remove `qt-creator` tag ...**

Answer (score 0):

Regarding structure packing:

In order to avoid alignment and padding issues you should consider.

- Rearranging the members.
- Adding the padding yourself.
- Telling the compiler to change the boundry of every member to 1 byte.

For instance:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct PROCESSING
{
    PROCESSOR Byte ;
    uint16_t count ;
    uint8_t overrange ;
    Status status ;
    Time timestamp ;
    float Field;
    float temperature ;
    float adc1;
    float dac1;
    float Field2;
    float Temperature;
    float adc2 ;
    float dac2 ;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Realigned to prevent padding where possible.

```
struct PROCESSING
{
    PROCESSOR Byte ; // 1 byte
    Status status ;  // 1 byte
    char __padding[2]; // 2 bytes

    uint16_t count ;   // 2 byte
    uint8_t overrange ; // 1 byte
    char _padding;      // 1 byte

    Time timestamp ; // 8 bytes

    float Field;
    float temperature ;
    float adc1;
    float dac1;
    float Field2;
    float Temperature;
    float adc2 ;
    float dac2 ;
};
```

**The standard *does not* guarantee that no padding will be applied by default!**
You should be sure for 1 thing. There ***will not*** be any padding at the beginning of the struct, after that you're on your own -by default-.

Comment: It still complains "Invalid Application of sizeof to incomplete type <false,46,45> .So, there is some fuzz going around with that 1 byte.

Comment: Did you count the bytes? What's the size of `PROCESSOR`,`Status`,`Time` ?

Comment: If you're on a x86 machine, *chances are* that the compiler would try to add padding between some members in order for the CPU to access them every `4 bytes` or `32 bits`.

Comment: Processer =1 byte , Status - 1 Byte , Time -8 bytes

Comment: Listen, reallign it so that they can be read as 4 byte chunks for instance ... after `PROCESSOR` add a `char padding[3]` ... total 4 bytes. Do this for the rest. Leave `Time` alone :D

Comment: Unless you're on a 64 bit processor which would love to be fed 8 bytes

Comment: @user2618994 If you're targetting multiple platforms, you should really use the preprocessor directive. Also, make sure ASSERT is functioning and if not open your program with a debugger such as `OllyDbg`.

Comment: Char padding[3] works . but my structure has to be exactly like above as its an interface with embedded system

Comment: I cant change the structure combinations because the binaries of the structuries has to match exactly with embedded system.So, the time and other variables cant be interchanged

Comment: @user2618994 If `pragma pack ..` doesn't work then I'm clueless

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the benefit of knowing how all of your user-defined types are defined, but your immediate issue seems to be that your PROCESSING struct somehow isn't completely defined.  Perhaps you're missing a #include of an appropriate header file or something.  Once that's resolved, if you need more information on how your structure is layed out in memory by your compiler, you might create some temporary debugging code, like this (note that I've taken the liberty of adding definitions of your types, which probably don't match your own definitions)....

```
typedef char PROCESSOR;
typedef char Status;
struct Time
{
char t[8];
};


struct PROCESSING
{
    PROCESSOR Byte ;
    uint16_t count ;
    uint8_t overrange ;
    Status status ;
    Time timestamp ;
    float Field;
    float temperature ;
    float adc1;
    float dac1;
    float Field2;
    float Temperature;
    float adc2 ;
    float dac2 ;
};


int main()
{
    PROCESSING p;

    printf("Member          Size  Offset\n"
        "-------------- ------ ------\n");

    #define MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(structMember) \
            printf("%14s ", #structMember); \
            printf(" %3d ", sizeof(p.structMember)); \
            printf("  %3d\n", offsetof(PROCESSING,structMember));

    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(Byte)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(count)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(overrange)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(status)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(timestamp)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(Field)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(temperature)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(adc1)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(dac1)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(Field2)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(Temperature)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(adc2)
    MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND(dac2)

    #undef MACROS_MAKE_THE_WORLD_GO_AROUND

    printf("\n   Total size of PROCESSING struct: %d bytes\n\n", sizeof(p));
}
```

When you run that, you'll see something like this:

```
Member          Size  Offset
-------------- ------ ------
          Byte    1     0
         count    2     2
     overrange    1     4
        status    1     5
     timestamp    8     6
         Field    4    16
   temperature    4    20
          adc1    4    24
          dac1    4    28
        Field2    4    32
   Temperature    4    36
          adc2    4    40
          dac2    4    44

   Total size of PROCESSING struct: 48 bytes
```

Once you have that, you're ready to begin figuring out what you might need to do to make your structure match the layout of your embedded system's structure layout, which may be more involved than simply making the structures the same overall size.  But the #pragma hints that others have given may be a good start.  Pay attention to padding that your compiler adds, which you can figure out by adding up the 'size' column & comparing it to the 'offset' column, and if they ever don't match, you know the compiler inserted some padding.